# Django - Userena not sending email

Tags: django, django-users, django-apps, django-email

I've installed the Userena app and have it running. I can register but no emails are being sent out. I'm overriding the signup form if that makes a difference. I'm not getting any error messages and I can see the users are being created in the database.

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

forms.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from userena.forms import SignupForm
from models import UserProfile, RefUserAge, RefUserReference, RefUserSport, RefUserView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  


class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
    age_pick = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = RefUserAge.objects.all())
    ref_pick = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = RefUserReference.objects.all())
    sport_pick = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = RefUserSport.objects.all())
    view_pick = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = RefUserView.objects.all())
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'), max_length=30, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'), max_length=30, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(SignupFormExtra, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def save(self):
        new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()
        new_user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
        new_user_profile

        new_user_profile.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        new_user_profile.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        new_user_profile.age_pick = self.cleaned_data['age_pick']
        new_user_profile.ref_pick = self.cleaned_data['ref_pick']
        new_user_profile.sport_pick = self.cleaned_data['sport_pick']
        new_user_profile.view_pick = self.cleaned_data['view_pick']
        new_user_profile.save()

        return new_user
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from models import UserProfile
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext
from forms import SignupFormExtra
from userena import views as userena_views

def signup_view(request):
    form = SignupFormExtra()
    response = userena_views.signup(request, signup_form=SignupFormExtra)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails are not being sent out because you have your email backend settings as [Dummy backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#dummy-backend)

As the name suggests the dummy backend does nothing with your messages

Change

```
django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend
```

To [SMTP backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#smtp-backend)

```
django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
```

Also, make sure

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

are the credentials for a valid inbox